# $\mu (A) = \sum_{i \in A} a_i$ is indeed a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(a_n)_{n > 0}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers. Let $I$ be an (index) set and let $$\mu: \mathcal{P}(I) \to [0, +\infty], \mu(A) = \sum_{i \in A}a_i, $$ where $\mathcal{P}(I)$ is the power set of $I$.
>
> My intention is to show that $\mu$ is a measure only by elementary methods, by which I mean I am looking for a solution not involving the integral of a measurable function or theorems like Fubini/Tonelli etc.

We quickly see that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, so now we only have to prove that for every sequence $(A_n)_{n}$ of mutually disjoint subsets of $I$, we have that $$\mu \left( \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(A_n). $$

Letting $\displaystyle A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and writing out $\mu$, we need to prove that $$\sum_{i \in A} a_i = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i \in A_n} a_i, $$ so, by using the supremum definition of a series over an arbitrary index set, that is $$\sum_{i \in J}a_i = \sup \left\{ \sum_{i \in K} a_i \ \mid \ K \text{ is a finite subset of } J \right\} \in [0, +\infty], $$ we have to prove that $$\sup \left\{ \sum_{i \in K} a_i \ \mid \ K \text{ is a finite subset of } A \right\} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sup \left\{ \sum_{i \in K} a_i \ \mid \ K \text{ is a finite subset of } A_n \right\}, $$ but I don't know how to do this. I tried  proving the $\leq$ and $\geq$ inequalities, but I haven't been able to. Specifically, I wasn't able to use the mutually disjointness property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $b_{in}=a_i$ if $i \in A_n$ and $0$ otherwise. Verify that $\sum_{i\in A} a_i=\sum_i \sum_n b_{in}$. This is where we use the fact that $A_n$s are disjoint and their union is $A$. So what remains is to show that $\sum_i \sum_n b_{in} =\sum_n \sum_i b_{in}$. For this it is enough to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_{in} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} b_{in}$ for each $N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_{in} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} b_{in}$. A can you handle this?

Comment: Yes, thank you!